# Paste new column based in info from another vector

Tags: r

I have a melted matrix called `matrix_cpm_spike_norm_mature_liver.Survival.m`. I want to add a new column named `Survival` based on the information in the `Survival` vector. The `Survival` vector is matched to `Mature_Hep` which again is the same as found in `variable` in the melted matrix. Please see output example

```
 > head(matrix_cpm_spike_norm_mature_liver.Survival.m)
        miRNA     variable     value
1  hsa-miR-101-3p Sa TxHep 092 10.315108
2  hsa-miR-10a-5p Sa TxHep 092 11.803228
3  hsa-miR-141-3p Sa TxHep 092  4.507543
4 hsa-miR-146b-5p Sa TxHep 092  6.890910
5 hsa-miR-148a-3p Sa TxHep 092 12.615621
6  hsa-miR-192-5p Sa TxHep 092 11.058548

> Survival
 [1] Dead  Alive Alive Alive Dead  Dead  Alive Alive Dead  Alive Alive Alive Alive Dead  Alive Alive Dead  Alive Alive
[20] Alive Alive Alive Alive Alive Alive Alive Alive Alive Alive Dead  Dead  Alive Dead  Alive Alive Dead  Alive Alive
[39] Alive Alive Alive Alive Alive Dead  Dead  Dead  Dead  Alive Dead  Dead  Dead  Dead  Dead  Dead  Dead  Alive Dead 
[58] Alive Dead  Dead  Alive Dead  Dead  Alive Dead  Alive Dead  Alive Dead  Dead  Alive Alive Alive Alive Alive Dead 
[77] Alive Alive Dead 
Levels: Alive Dead

> colnames(Mature_Hep)
 [1] "Sa TxHep 092"   "Sa TxHep 112"   "Sa TxHep 121"   "Sa TxHep 164"   "Sb TxHep 008"   "Sc TxHep 008"   "Sb TxHep 014"  
 [8] "Sc TxHep 018"   "Sb TxHep 082"   "Sa TxHep 084"   "Sa MM-7"        "Sa TxHep 086"   "Sa TxHep 088"   "Sa TxHep 094"  
[15] "Sa TxHep 096"   "Sa TxHep 102"   "Sa TxHep 113"   "Sa TxHep 120"   "Sa TxHep 134"   "Sa Tx Hep 140 " "Sa TxHep 144"  
[22] "Sc D-10"        "Sa TxHep 145"   "Sa TxHep 146"   "Sa TxHep 157"   "Sc TxHep 158"   "Sa TxHep 161"   "Sa TxHep 176"  
[29] "Sc TxHep 185"   "Sa TxHep 186"   "Sc TxHep 192"   "Sa TxHep 201"   "Sa S-26"        "Sa TxHep 204"   "Sb TxHep 215"  
[36] "Sb TxHep 236"   "Sa CD-21"       "Sa MT-27"       "Sb MP-32"       "Sa GD-38"       "Sc CG-39"       "Sc-DG-45"      
[43] "Sc PC-46"       "Sa VS-29"       "Sb 1018"        "Sb 1065"        "Sb 1068"        "Sb 1104"        "Sd 1167"       
[50] "Sc 1196"        "Sb 1222"        "Sb 1237"        "Sb 1241"        "Sc 1302"        "Sa BF-33"       "Sb 1304"       
[57] "Sb 1322"        "Sc 1372"        "Sa 1474"        "Sc 1532"        "Sd 1540"        "Sb 1588"        "Sa 1604"       
[64] "Sc 1743"        "Sb 1808"        "Sc TxHep 015"   "Sa 1809"        "Sd 1859"        "Sb 1894"        "Sb 2218"       
[71] "Sb 2239"        "Sa HEP 014"     "Sb HEP 015"     "Sa HEP 018"     "Sb HEP 020"     "Sa TxHep 080"   "Sa HEP 045"    
[78] "Sa TxHep 090"   "Sa TxHep 091"
```

Output:

```
        miRNA     variable     value      Survival
1  hsa-miR-101-3p Sa TxHep 092 10.315108  Dead
2  hsa-miR-10a-5p Sa TxHep 092 11.803228  Dead
3  hsa-miR-141-3p Sa TxHep 092  4.507543  Dead
4 hsa-miR-146b-5p Sa TxHep 092  6.890910  Dead
5 hsa-miR-148a-3p Sa TxHep 092 12.615621  Dead
6  hsa-miR-192-5p Sa TxHep 092 11.058548  Dead
```

Comment: Anything you've already tried? hint: `?merge`

Comment: I know the merge function but I am not sure how to utilize it in this case

Comment: You probably need a dataframe with a survival column, and a 'variable' (or whatever) column containing the strings you want to merge on. Then you can do something like `res <- merge(mylargematrix, mynewdata, by="variable")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert matrix to data frame and do merge() :

```
Survival <- c("Dead","Alive","Alive","Alive")
Mature_Hep <- c("Sa TxHep 092","Sa TxHep 112","Sa TxHep 121","Sa TxHep 164")

df <- as.data.frame(Survival)
df <- cbind(df,Mature_Hep)

miRNA <- c("hsa-miR-101-3p","hsa-miR-10a-5p")
variable <- c("Sa TxHep 092","Sa TxHep 112")
df1 <- as.data.frame(miRNA)
df1 <- cbind(df1,variable)

result <- merge(df1,df,by.x = c("variable"),by.y = c("Mature_Hep"))
```